# Invalid number of channels in input image error?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to pass a numpy 2d array that represents an image into the cvtColor function. The image is grayscale. Here is some of the code:

```
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Img is just a 2d numpy grayscale array. However, when I try to run this, I get this error:

> Invalid number of channels in input image:
> 'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
> 'scn' is 1

I have no idea what this means. Could someone clarify what is going on here and help me fix it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Hard to know without the input image. Maybe it is already grayscale (1 channel) and you are trying to convert it from BGR (3 channel) to grayscale.

Comment: Your cvtColor command is expecting a 3-channel img. Perhaps your img is already 1-channel.